# error in running bash script as root

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo

I have a simple shutdown script which i want to run as root

```
shutdown -h +30;
echo "succesfull";
```

I have followed these answer[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/167885/158636),[2](https://askubuntu.com/a/425762/158636) to make my script root.

first I run this command

```
sudo chown root.root $HOME/test/test.sh
sudo chmod 4755 $HOME/test/test.sh
```

and then made changes in sudoers

```
sudo visudo
```

added this command after this line `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

```
eka ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: $HOME/test/test.sh
```

But when i executed my script its showing this error

```
shutdown: Need to be root
succesfull
```

Comment: `chmod 4755` - I assume you meant to make a setuid script? Scripts can't be made setuid.

Comment: @muru I was following the answer 1

Comment: That user is mistaken. setuid doesn't work on scripts. Period.

Comment: @muru thanks for the info.. but how to revert back to normal executable script whether this code be enough `sudo chmod +x $HOME/test/test.sh`

Comment: You need to do `chmod u-s`, but as I said, it doesn't matter - setuid doesn't affect scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html) use setuid shell scripts, the SUID bit is not honored on shell scripts anyway on current systems. Use `sudo` instead, as you attempted anyway:

```
eka   ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/eka/test/test.sh
```

And then:

```
eka$ sudo ~/test/test.sh
```

With that, `test.sh` will be executed as "root". No need to use setuid here.

Comment: How to execute by double clicking the script?

Comment: That follow-up is an entirely different question, see [How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows)