# How to execute a sudo script with double click

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shutdown

I have this script to shutdown my system after 30 seconds. I want to run this script by double clicking it (that option I changed in nautilus). This is the content of my script

```
#!/bin/bash
shutdown -h +30;
echo "succesfull"
read -p "Press any key to continue... " -n1 -s
```

to make sudo script executable without a password I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/626917/158636) and I am able to execute this script from the terminal without using a password (`sudo ~/test/test.sh`). The problem is when I double click the above script it's again asking for root privileges:

```
shutdown: Need to be root
successful
Press any key to continue...
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: make a .desktop file? http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Comment: @Tim thanks but Is it  possible to execute shell script (double click) itself without creating a .desktop file?

Comment: possibly... But you may keep having issues. A launcher is the standard way to do it. The command can be `./path/to/script` of course. I take it you've make the script executable?

Comment: yes i made it executable and if i want to add it in a startup application (with additional codes) should we have to call the desktop file or the shell script

Comment: To add to a startup application, you can either put the launcher in `./config/autostart` or in another script, set to start by referencing the script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a conditional to relaunch the script as root if it's launched as a normal user.

---

**To shutdown the computer:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $USER == "eka" ]]; then       # If the script is ran as "eka" then...
    sudo $0                         # relaunch it as "root".
    exit 0                          # Once it finishes, exit gracefully.
elif [[ $USER != "root" ]]; then    # If the user is not "eka" nor "root" then...
    exit 0                          # Once it finishes, exit gracefully.
fi                                  # End if.

shutdown -h +30;
read -p "Press any key to continue... " -n1 -s
```

**Simplified version:**

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $USER == "eka" ]] && { sudo $0; exit 0; }
[[ $USER != "root" ]] && exit 0

shutdown -h +30;
```

**Very simplified version (not recommended):**

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo $0          # Relaunch script as root (even if it's already running as root)
shutdown -h +30; # Shutdown the computer in 30 seconds.
```

---

**To suspend the computer:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $USER == "eka" ]]; then                 # If the script is ran as "eka":
    gnome-screensaver-command -a                  # Lock computer.
else                                          # Else:
    sudo -u eka gnome-screensaver-command -a      # Once it finishes, exit gracefully.
fi                                            # End if.
```

**Simplified version:**

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $USER != "eka" ]] && { sudo -u eka gnome-screensaver-command -a; exit 0; }
```

**Very simplified version:**

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u eka gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

---

**Note:** `$0` is a variable that holds the full path to the script.

Comment: Great thanks it works but can you just explain the if condition part a little bit for more clarity

Comment: @Eka: Check now.

Comment: I think you should add an extra security check - make sure the user running the script *is* the user who wants to double click.  system accounts shouldn't be able to access or use the script, IMO.

Comment: @Helio is it possible to relaunch script as a user  `eka` instead of `root` because i am also using this script `gnome-screensaver-command -a ` to lock the computer but using root we cant lock a computer.

Comment: @Eka: Try now. **;-)**