# Can I get Network Manager to unload/load the wireless driver?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, modprobe

Sometimes my wireless loses connection and will not reconnect. However, I find it will reconnect when I open terminal and run

```
sudo modprobe -r nameOfDriver
sudo modprobe nameOfDriver
```

However, going to Network Manager and un-checking enable wireless and enable wireless does not fix the problem.

Is there any way to have network manager remove the driver via `modprobe`? What exactly is disabling in network manager (or with the hardware/keyboard switch) do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Disabling a wireless connection in Network Manager deactivates the wireless interface (similar to `ifdown` or `ifconfig down`), and then soft-blocks (turns off) the hardware device. It *does not* unload the wireless driver (kernel module).
- The hardware/keyboard wireless switch will also soft-block (or hard-block, i.e. cut power) the internal wireless card.
- You can customize -- to a limited degree -- what happens when Network Manager enables/disables an interface by editing scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`; see `man NetworkManager` for more info.

  - **BUT** this cannot be used to load/unload the driver via *modprobe*, because once Network Manager unloads the driver, the interface ceases to exist and it won't be able to bring it back up! (notice when you `modprobe -r` that the Wireless options completely disappear from the drop-down menu)

So, the best option is to setup a custom keyboard shortcut to a script which unloads/loads the driver; you can add that script to the `sudoers` file such that no `sudo` is needed for it. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-my-python-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password) for details.

Answer (score -1):

modprobe -r is removing the driver but only for the session. To do so permanently, you would need to blacklist it, but I don't remember how sorry. the wireless button/switch is meant to turn off your wifi by disabling the driver btw.

Comment: The wireless switch blocks the hardware device, it has nothing to with the kernel module.

Comment: In fact it does, since the blocking is handled by the kernel module of the corresponding wireless adapter.

Comment: @Cumulus007 does it "disable the driver btw"?

Comment: It doesn't, but your statement the wireless switch has nothing to do with the kernel module is simply not true.

Comment: @Cumulus007: so you are telling me that the *hardware* button/switch on the laptop to turn wireless on/off, which presumably works on *any OS* depends on the Linux kernel module?