# Run script at user login as root, with a catch

Tags: samba, sudo, root

I'm trying to run a PHP script as root on user login.  The PHP script adds a Samba share to the Samba config, thus the need for root privileges.  The only issue here, is that the user doesn't exist yet.  This system is integrated with active directory.  So when a user logs in for the first time, a home directory for them is created under `/home/DOMAIN/username`.

I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password) and that seems like the correct way to get what I want, but I'm having trouble with the syntax since I don't know the user's name.

Would it be something like:

`ALL     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/DOMAIN/*/createSambaShare.php`

This doesn't seem to work as it is currently.  Anyone have any ideas or a "scripted" way to add a Samba share on user login?

Since I've made other changes to `/etc/skel`, I just added the bash necessary to run the PHP script in .profile in there.  This then gets copied to the "new" user's home and it tries to run the PHP script.  But it fails, because these are not privileged users.

Changing permissions on the PHP script will not help.  It needs to be run as sudo because it opens the Samba config file for writing.  Letting any user run the PHP script would result in a PHP error.

The `homes` Samba directive doesn't work for my use case.  I need the Samba share to exist once they exist on the server, even when they're not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put the script in the user's home directory. Instead, put it in a fixed location. If the script needs some user-dependent arguments, make the script read that from a file — but you don't even need that since you're copying the script from `/etc/skel` anyway.

If you allow a user to run a script in their home directory with elevated privileges, then they can replace the script by another script. So your proposed rule would be equivalent from a security point of view to

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/skel/createSambaShare.php
MANY ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

where `MANY` is any user whose home directory is under `/home/DOMAIN`. (Ok, unless a user's home directory is owned by root, not writable to the user, and the script is not writable by or owned by the user either. But that would be pretty unusual.)

Also, I recommend not using `ALL` in a User specification. Restrict the rule to a group.

```
%sambasharers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/createSambaShare.php
```

Comment: My thought with including it in their home directory is that I would remove it once the share was created.  In your scenario, how would I know if it had been ran for a particular user?

Comment: All the script takes in is a user name and I send it that through bash in .profile

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Your proposal wouldn't work: a user could run the script in another user's directory. Since the script is running with extra privileges, it can store the information elsewhere, as it must. The script must also determine the calling user by itself, since the caller could pass any argument it wants; use the environment variable `SUDO_UID`.

Comment: Would it work to create a file in the user's home directory that is owned by root upon successful completion of the script?  Then I would know if it had ran or not and ensures that nothing "runs" out of the user's directory.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 No, it doesn't help much to have the file owned by root if it's located in a directory that's writable by the user: the user could substitute any other file owned by root by making a symbolic link, and there's no practical way to check this that doesn't have race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put it in `/etc/profile` and it should execute at any successful login.
2. Add execution privilege to all users for that script file. Open terminal and type this command:

   ```
   sudo chmod ugo+x script
   ```

Comment: The PHP script needs sudo because it edits the Samba config.  Letting the script be run by any old user would not solve that because of the Samba config permissions.