# Applying password with command in Terminal

Tags: command-line, password

Is there an option to apply a password with the command in the terminal? Somethhing like:

```
sudo some-command -pass=mypass
```

I'm just curious, I know that this is not safe.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter

Comment: @muru Heh, thanks, I was searching in askubuntu, it was logical to me that the answer will be here :)

Comment: Indeed, that question really belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: @Wilf sudo command, like my example above

Comment: Try this question: [Execute sudo without Password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

Comment: @Wilf you are missing the point, I want to know is there a way to execute a single command with root access. Let say, I have a script that execute in terminal when I open it, so the script, let say `sudo apt-get update` will prompt me for password, but I only want to execute this command, without a prompt for password.   Best example, starting lampp. I wrote a script,and I don't want to enter password in terminal, I want to eneter password in script directly, so it will execute without prompting me for password.

Comment: There is [a question](http://askubuntu.com/q/155791/178596) that might help with that as well...

Comment: Thats the right thing. Thanks a lot for your answer. I can't give you vote up now because i don't have enough points.