# run ap-hotspot commands from a saved file

Tags: wireless, bash, permissions, hot-spot

How can I create a text file to automatically run these commands:

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
sudo ap-hotspot configure
sudo ap-hotspot stop
sudo ap-hotspot restart
```

One file for each command.

I tried with creating a file ".sh" that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
ap-hotspot start
```

Also used:

```
chown root:root <start-a-p>.sh
chmod 4755 <start-a-p>.sh
```

to give permissions.

But it doesn't work. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: try `chmod +x <start-a-p>.sh` and btw, if you are using the `<` in the file name, that may break it...

Comment: Still not working. And i do not use `<`. That was just for example.

Comment: For that then it would be simpler to run the entire script with sudo, a way to do it without prompting for password can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password/155827#155827)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following content in script (.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /bin/bash -c "ap-hotspot start"
```

Make it a script by executing `chmod +x filename.sh`

and run it if you are in parent folder `./filename.sh` or full path.

Comment: I would like the script without `sudo` in it as I want to open so it can run the command without asking for the password.