# What are the files needs to be edit to add a user? and what to be write?

Tags: permissions, programming, c, adduser

I am trying to write a C program to add a new user to my Ubuntu 14.04.
 I edited
1) /etc/passwd

```
sachin:x:65535:1:sachin:/home/sachin:/bin/bash
```

2) /etc/shadow

```
sachin:$6$VwBWgroA$t4KXLWIf81sWtiA1/a.fRLrXaOAflGtMo73hGvCzp/M6S8oizZ4iqk.vYbkblXZj2hgGXJxlJ.M2hghGO.a650:16294::::::
```

3) .profile

```
stty istrip
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/share/bin:.
export PATH
```

---

After this when I run - `ls -l /home/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 43 mrcr mrcr 4096 Aug 12 10:27 mrcr
d-w------t  2 sachin    daemon    4096 Aug 12 11:11 sachin
```

Where "sachin" is created by my rpogram, "mrcr" is created normally.
I changed the permissions like a normal user home

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 sachin    daemon    4096 Aug 12 11:11 sachin
```

I copied all files from "mrcr" home directory to "sachin" home directory(.bashrc, Desktop ..etc)

Now in login screen "sachin" is there to login. but even if I enter correct password I can't login into it. It will load again the same login screen.
given below is my entire code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct passwd *userlist;
    int count, usernumber, len1;
    FILE *tmp, *stmp, *mailer, *profile;
    char *commentfield, *username, *userdir, *home;
    char *mailcomment, *mailmail, reply;

    commentfield = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    username = (char *)malloc(8*sizeof(char));
    userdir = (char *)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    home = (char *)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    mailcomment = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    mailmail = (char *)malloc(512*sizeof(char));

    if (argc!=4)
    {
        printf("usage : %s [dirname- no slashes] [logname] [comment - in quotes]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (strlen(argv[2]) < 5) || (strlen(argv[2]) > 8) )
    {
        printf("pls enter logname between 5-8 \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

    setpwent();

    count = 0;

    while((userlist = getpwent()) != NULL)
    {
        if(count < userlist->pw_uid)
        {
            count = userlist->pw_uid ; 
            usernumber = count + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("usernumber : %d\n", usernumber);

    endpwent();

    sprintf(commentfield,"%s", argv[3]);
    sprintf(username, "%s", argv[2]);
    sprintf(userdir, "%s", argv[1]);
    sprintf(home, "/%s/%s", argv[1], argv[2]);



    printf("\n Check this out here: \n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n username      :\t %s", username);
    printf("\n Home Directory:\t %s", home);
    printf("\n comment       :\t %s", commentfield);
    printf("\n______________________________________________\n\n");

    printf("all of this ok? n/y: ");
    scanf("%c", &reply);

    if(reply != 'y')
    {
        printf("\n exiting....u entered not y");
        exit(1);
    } 

    tmp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "a");
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\npermission denied\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(tmp, "%s:x:%d:1:%s:%s:/bin/bash\n", username, usernumber, commentfield, home);
    fclose(tmp);



    stmp = fopen("/etc/shadow", "a");
    if (stmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\npermission denied\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stmp, "%s:*LK*:::::::\n", username);
    fclose(stmp);

    mkdir(home, 0755);
    chdir(home);


    profile = fopen(".profile", "a");
    fprintf(profile, "stty istrip\n");
    fprintf(profile, "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/share/bin:.\n");
    fprintf(profile, "export PATH\n");
    fprintf(profile, "\n\n");
    fclose(profile);

    chown(home, usernumber, 1);
    chown(".profile", usernumber, 1);
    chmod(".profile", 0644);


    printf("\n\nALL done!!!!!!!\n Now set the password: ");
    execl("/usr/bin/passwd", "passwd", username, NULL);
    printf("\n\n SUCCESS PASSWORD IS SET.....BYE!!!\n\n");

}
```

QUESTIONS:

1. what are the files needs to be edit?
2. How can i run the program without to be a root?
3. what changes i needs to put in my code?

Comment: If you really want to rewrite the `adduser` command line tool, maybe you could get its code from the Ubuntu sources.

Comment: Or just use a bash script/command, as all the utils are available there. N.B. it needs to be done as root, creating/changing users is a admin job - see also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password).

Comment: Can you login via terminal? (Press `Ctrl-Alt-F2` to get to one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post answer but note that there is tool [`adduser`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/adduser) which is less error-prone and more complex.

1. Source - http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/adduser.html

> 11.2.4. Creating a user by hand
>
> To create a new account manually, follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Edit /etc/passwd with vipw and add a new line for the new account. Be careful with > the syntax. Do not edit directly with an editor! vipw locks the file, so that other commands won't try to update it at the same time. You should make the password field be `*', so that it is impossible to log in.
>
> Similarly, edit /etc/group with vigr, if you need to create a new group as well.
>
> Create the home directory of the user with mkdir.
>
> Copy the files from /etc/skel to the new home directory.
>
> Fix ownerships and permissions with chown and chmod. The -R option is most useful. > The correct permissions vary a little from one site to another, but usually the following commands do the right thing:
>
> cd /home/newusername
> chown -R username.group .
> chmod -R go=u,go-w .
> chmod go= .
>
> Set the password with passwd.
> ```
>
> After you set the password in the last step, the account will work. You shouldn't set it until everything else has been done, otherwise the user may inadvertently log in while you're still copying the files.

1. You can use [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/) (formerly known as `Policy Kit`).

3.:

- `main` function should be returning integer (`int`).
- don't copy `.profile`, copy whole `/etc/skel` directory

Comment: thanksss...actually i did the work already...in the same manner u sed....you are right...and thanks for the answer..:)