# Problem with gnome-terminal, but not with xterm?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, xterm

I have a script called `start-hotspot-terminal.sh`. The text in it is:

```
#! /bin/bash
x-terminal-emulator -e "sudo /home/user/tools/start-hotspot.sh; read -p 'Press [Enter] to close terminal.';"
```

There is another script called `start-hotspot.sh`. The text in it is:

```
#! /bin/bash
ap-hotspot start
```

I have done all the necessary things to execute `start-hotspot.sh` with root privileges without requiring the password. Basically, I read and followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password) . So the `sudo` in the `start-hotspot-terminal.sh` should not be a problem.
When I simply run `sudo /home/user/tools/start-hotspot.sh` from the terminal, the hotspot starts without asking me for the password.

But now, when I run the `start-hotspot-terminal.sh` I am prompted for the password. 
When I replace the `x-terminal-emulator` with `xterm`, there is no problem and the hotspot starts!

Why does this happen? Any way to fix it?

System:
Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, Default terminal is gnome-terminal

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4465930/3701431