# How do I tell a shell script my password?

Tags: apt, sudo, scripts

I've been trying to create a script that runs `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` whenever I log in. It goes like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
(sudo apt-get update)
(sudo apt-get autoremove)
```

But whenever I run the script it freezes my computer. I'm assuming it's because it's waiting for the script to supply a password. Would it work if I added `PASSWD:mypassword` after the commands like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
(sudo apt-get update)PASSWD:mypassword
(sudo apt-get autoremove)PASSWD:mypassword
```

or is there something else I should do? Is there even a way? If so please tell me!

Comment: Unattended Upgrades can do regular runs of both for you. Do you need to write your half-baked solution for this?

Comment: What is Unattended Upgrades?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html. One of its configuration options (in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`) is to allow automatic runs of `autoremove`.

Comment: Don't run your commands in subshells: remove the parentheses

Comment: Alternately, give yourself privilege to run `sudo apt-get` without a password. Create a file named `/etc/sudoers.d/willem` containing `willem ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get` -- assuming "willem" is your username

Comment: @glennjackman You actually guessed my username right... anyhow I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: But what if I don't have permission? I'm an admin but...

Comment: You will do `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/willem` to create/edit that file

Comment: Would it be doing it right to run 'sudo visudo -f  /etc/sudoers.d/willem'  and then type in 'willem ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get', press CTRL+S and close the terminal?

Comment: How you run the script? And remove the parentheses.

Comment: I have it configured so that I click on it and it runs

Comment: Ok, so I put a file in /etc/sudoers.d/ that says "willem ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get" but then when I type a sudo command it returns "sudo:  /etc/sudoers.d/willem is mode 0664, should be 0440". What do I do about this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually have to include your password in your script (from what I have seen its generally not advisable to have your password in a script). Instead you can edit your sudoer file to allow you to run the apt-get command without the need for a password.

For more information go to [this website](http://www.howtogeek.com/116757/8-ways-to-tweak-and-configure-sudo-on-ubuntu/).

open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

Enter the command

```
sudo visudo
```

At the end of the sudoers file type

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Where username is your username (obviously)

editing this file will allow you to run any of the apt-get commands without entering a password. This means you can also install or upgrade packages without entering your password.

You can also add other comands to this list by entering the path to the command after a comma. The path to a command can be found by entering the following command in a terminal.

```
which command
```

Where command is the name of the command( for example reboot).

Comment: Another solution here would be make the script with `apt-get` `update` & `autoremove` commands, and save it so only root could modify it, then link that in the sudoers file. Very similar thing here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Comment: Thanks for the info I didn't really know about that method though it seems a little complex

Answer (score 0):

*The command to start a bash sccript :*

#!/bin/bash

*The command to ask for the users root password :*

[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo bash "$0" "$@"

*Example commands of what can be next :*

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade --yes

shutdown -r now

*Good luck with your script*

Answer (score -1):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S apt-get update
echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S apt-get autoremove
```

Here, you echo your password and the read the password using **-S** option (stdin option for sudo).

Comment: Sorry by this will show your password in `ps` so anyone that has access to the system can find out the admin password.

Comment: @Rinzwind how to echo the characters "$@!" ?

Comment: You should escape them, but don't use this please. Use the method with visusoers.