# Jenkins sudo password

Tags: automation, jenkins

I have install jenkins in ubuntu OS. when i build a project and run some executable shell script then it doen't access the file. how to add sudo password in shell script.

Comment: "how to add sudo password in shell script." why?! bad idea. Please learn how to add users to a group and how to set executable permissions for a group.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell a shell script my password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612142/how-do-i-tell-a-shell-script-my-password)

Answer (score 0):

Kartik,As Rinzwind has already advised you that this is the bad idea and must be ignored or find other way around, by setting executable permissions to the user/group, but for the purpose of educational only, I am adding the possible solution, Pl check let me know if it can help you

create a bash script `mysudo` # you can name it anything

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "your_password" | sudo -S sleep 1 && sudo su
```

wait for 1 second so the echoed password could be filled in

replace `your_password` with your `actual password`