# How to run an autostart application as root?

Tags: permissions, vpn, autostart

I am currently using a VPN application that requires administrative privileges and I have added the application to my autostart. However, every time I login, I will always be asked to enter my password to grant the permissions to this application, which I very redundant since I just used the same password to login.

Is there anyway I can have this application automatically start without being required to enter my password? I have already tried making the autostart command `sudo airvpn`, but that causes the application to not open at all.

To clarify, I am not looking to run a command on boot, I am looking to run a command at login. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866412/how-to-run-a-command-that-requires-sudo-at-login) is relevant, however, I have tried adding `exec airvpn` to `/etc/rc.local`, and nothing happens on login.

Comment: @dessert As mentioned in my most recent edit, I am not looking to run a command on boot, but rather on login.

Comment: Why `exec airvpn` instead of just `/path/to/airvpn` (full path may be needed!) or – if it's a bash script – `bash /path/to/airvpn`?

Comment: I added `bash /usr/bin/airvpn` which is the absolute path to the application. The following works in terminal, but nothing happens when added to `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running a graphical program, perhaps you should avoid `sudo`, as it can only ask you for your password via a terminal window, which is not good for graphical programs. (Unless you are launching said programs from a terminal.) I used to recommend `gksu` or `gksudo`, but sadly both programs have been discontinued, and are no longer available in recent versions of Ubutnu. You can instead use policykit to run the program as root using `pkexec airvpn`. That too requires a password, but can prompt for a password with a graphical pop-up window,and thus does not depend on the password being typed into a terminal.

If you don't want to enter your password every time, here are some tips on how to execute a program as root without typing your password.

## setuid

If the `airvpn` executable is a binary file (as opposed to a text file), you should be able to use the chmod command to change the file permissions to activate the setuid mode, meaning it will always run as the user who owns it. (To make sure that user is root, run `sudo chroot $(which airvpn)`.) This will not require a password, and will not require you to do any of the steps below. It will, however, require you to run the following command: `sudo chmod u+s $(which airvpn)`. However, this trick does not work with text files (python programs, shell scripts, etc.). Also, if you ever update this file, you will probably have to do this again. And again the next time you update it. And again...

## Make a `sudo` config file

BTW, `sudo` (and by extension `gksudo` and `gksu`, which both use the same configurations as `sudo`) and policykit (which can execute program as root using `pkexec`) can both be programmed to run a program without the need to enter a password. IDK how to do this with policykit, but I can teach you how to achieve this with `sudo`. Before you continue, you should have a root shell running in the background, just in case something goes wrong. (You may lose your ability to use `sudo` at all, see below). Create a text file in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. You can call it whatever you want, as long as it doesn't have a `.` character, and doesn't end with a `~` character.

Before I continue, I should warn you that you'll need to know the path to your `airvpn` executable. If you enter `which airvpn` into your terminal, it should tell you where this file is. Assuming it's `/usr/bin/airvpn`, you can type:

```
    %admin ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/airvpn
```

and save it in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. It's probably a good idea to use the `chmod` command to set the file permissions to 0440. You can do that by running (as root) `chmod 0440 file`, replacing "file" with the name of the newly-created file.

Now, open a **new** terminal, and test this new configuration by running `sudo airvpn`. (The reason the word "new" is in bold is because `sudo` might not ask you for a password if you've already executed a `sudo` command in an existing terminal, even if you haven't successfully configured `sudo` to avoid asking you for a password.) If you were able to do this in a new terminal, you've successfully made it possible to execute `airvpn` without a password. Now all you have to do is change your startup item to run `sudo airvpn`, and you'll be good to go. This will work regardless of whether the executable file is a binary file or a text file. Also, you should only need to do this once, regardless of how often you update this program.

## Oh no! It didn't work, and now sudo gives me errors!

If something goes wrong, and you lose your ability to use `sudo` to execute anything as root, you can delete your newly-created file, and sudo should behave as it did before. (Remember when I advised you to keep a root shell running? You'll probably need it to delete that file. Of course, you could execute a root shell by running `pkexec su`, and then use that to delete the file. Or, if the root account has a password, `su` should do.)

## gksudo replacement

Although gksudo may be dead, there is a way to make a similar replacement yourself. Step one, install the ssh-askpass package: `sudo apt install ssh-askpass`. Then, create a shell script (using whatever your favorite text editor is), with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass
exec sudo "$@"
```

You can save it as `gksudo`. Now, you need to make that script executable, and copy it somewhere where you can execute it. You could combine the he `install` command will let you do both of those things at the same time: `sudo install -o 0 -g 0 -m 0755 ./install /usr/local/sbin`. (If you don't have a `/usr/local/sbin` directory, you might want to make one: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin`.) You may also want to run `rm install`, so that you don't have a useless second copy lying around.

Now you can type `gksudo airvpn`, and you'll get a non-terminal prompt to type your password. You can re-use this to make an application launcher, a startup item, or whatever else. Since this script relies on `sudo` as a backend, any configurations you make to `sudo` will apply here, as well. Thus, this could become a fallback in case your `sudo` config fails - unless you can't do anything with sudo, in which case you're on your own. (So, for example, if your `/etc/sudoers.d/*` file gets deleted for whatever reason.)

Comment: From what I gather, it's best to edit the sudoers.d directory via the `visudo` command.