# Openvpn start at boot fails because service needs root password

Tags: boot, networking, password, root, openvpn

In Ubuntu 18.04, I have my Surfshark VPN service configured to start at boot. However, something is requiring my root password to start the VPN so the boot startup fails. I can start it just fine from a desktop terminal or in NetworkManager. How can I configure the service to bypass the root password requirement? TIA for any help.

Regards,
Steve Silvi

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [#963672](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963672/how-to-run-an-autostart-application-as-root/963694). You should refer to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Surfshark config file located in `/etc/openvpn` had the original .ovpn file extension. After changing it to a .conf extension as suggested in the [maketecheasier.com article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/connect-vpn-automatically-linux/), the VPN is now activated at boot time.